# How to pass an ALT key press through SSH connection to tmux using suckless simple terminal emulator?

Tags: ssh, keyboard, terminal, tmux, alt

On my local machine I have suckless simple terminal and tmux with the settings like this:

```
bind-key -n M-k next-window
```

where I am binding an action to a key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>k</kbd>.

It perfectly works on local machine, but if I launch tmux with the same config on remote, it does not translate an <kbd>Alt</kbd> key press to remote, so I am not able to execute commands which include <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.

Maybe you know solution or in which direction to dig in?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190349/alt-key-not-working-in-emacs-sshing-x11) help?

Comment: @Ramhound nope :(

Answer (score 0):

Everything is working fine, just old versions of tmux are not loading config from `.config/tmux/tmux.com`